# this is my gwt code if i goto another tab in tabpanel...popup still exist..i have attached the snaps

Tags: gwt

```java
if (checked) {
    int left = toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteLeft();
```

---

```java
    int top =  toothWidget.getVPanel().getAbsoluteTop();//toothWidget.getToothImage().getAbsoluteTop();
    Image im = new Image();                                         
    im.setUrl("images/"+ toothWidget.getToothNumber()+ menuItem.getImg());
    int offx = left;                                                
    int offy = top;                                                 
    final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel();                      
    popup.setStylePrimaryName("transparent");                       
    popup.setPopupPosition(Math.max(offx, 0),Math.max(offy, 0));    
    //popup.add(im);                                                
    ToothWidget wgt = new ToothWidget(toothWidget.getToothNumber(),toothWidget.getToothNumber()+menuItem.getImg(), toothWidget.getTeeth());
    toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).put(menuItem.getName(), wgt);
    wgt.setMenu(toothWidget.getMenu());                             
    wgt.setPanel(popup);                                            
    popup.add(wgt);                                                 
    popup.show();                                                   
}                                                           
else {                                                      
    ToothWidget wgt = toothWidget.getTeeth().getMap().get(toothWidget.getToothNumber()).remove(menuItem.getName());
    wgt.getPanel().hide();                                          
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use "Code Sample" tag and ensure your question becomes readable. Also add in a few more details on GWT version, third party jars based on gwt if you are using them, etc.

Comment: Did u try creating Popupanel with constructor argument true?

Comment: i have tried it....but if i clicked on previous tab than popup disappears

Comment: i mean if i go to another tab than popup shoud disappear and if i come back to previous tab i want popup still there..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use debugger to figure out what part of code doesn't work as expected?
Maybe your else-block isn't reached, or toothWidget.gePanel() doesn't return your PopupPanel..